# Creating a production branch from development for a J2EE project

Tags: java, spring, maven, development-environment, production-environment

I have a java web application managed and built via maven with several independent sub projects. I build them all and finally all subproject's dependencies are added to web application. Now I'm planning to separate the production and development environment. All subprojects have somehow different connection URLs (for database, web service, etc.) and specifically these URLs will change on production environment. I am planning to use Spring's placeholder to manage those URLs and other properties on different execution environments, but what do you think, I am open to use maven assembly plugin and create different jar/war files for each subproject and main project.

Have any other ideas on that subject?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SachinVerma, could please concentrate on the question itself, not details?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want different branches, version, deliverable for different environments. You want the same deliverable for each environment.

You already mention that you use placeholders/spring configuration then use it. Put the properties file(s) somewhere on the file-system (`/etc/conf/yourapp` or something) and read it from that location in your app. You might want to put in some sensible defaults (like hibernate dialect, etc.).

Another thing you might want to look into is [profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html) as you might want to load different beans in development and production (i.e. development local configured datasource, production jndi lookup for the datasource).

Comment: You're right, "branch" does not fit what i want. But consider a case that a.jar is used by b.jar. And also assume that there are property files such a-dev.properties, a-prod.properties, etc. So I'm gonna export two different jars, a-dev.jar and a-prod.jar. But I want b-dev.jar to use a-dev.jar and b-prod.jar to use a-prod.jar. I couldn't make my mind how to deal with this situation.